# Convert DICOM tag into something more readable

Tags: python, dicom, pydicom

I'm working with [pydicom](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/) and a [DICOMWeb client](https://dicomweb-client.readthedocs.io/). The latter I use to fetch metadata from a DICOM repository.

When retrieving DICOM metadata, I only get the DICOM tags as tuples of hexadecimals. I was wondering how to look up the tags and get a readable identifier using pydicom.

For example, how to convert the tag `0x10,0x20` into its string representation/keyword (`"PatientID"`)? (See specs of the [DICOM data dictionary](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/html/part06.html))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pydicom offers [some utility functions](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/dev/reference/datadict.html) to handle the [DICOM data dictionary](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/html/part06.html):

```py
import pydicom as dicom 

tag = dicom.tag.Tag(0x10,0x20)

# Option 1) Retrieve the keyword:
keyword = dicom.datadict.keyword_for_tag(tag)
# Option 2) Retrieve the complete datadict entry:
entry = dicom.datadict.get_entry(tag)
representation, multiplicity, name, is_retired, keyword = entry

# keyword: "PatientID"
# name: "Patient ID"
```